# How to use css inside component folder Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs/nextjs and right now i am trying to use css inside "component" folder, For this i tried with following code but not working for me,home.module.css path is "styles/homemodule.css" (styles folder in root),Where i am wrong ?

```
import homeStyles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions, and edit this question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow, or it may be closed.

Answer (score 2):

there is no need to import css file in your specific component
just import css file to your root component (App.jsx) like

```
import "../styles/Home.module.css"
```

and now anywhere you can use classes defined in `Home.module.css` file

Comment: And if you want to use global CSS, you need to import it in the _app level: 

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet